# Rounding of semidefinite programms using simplex

Tags: discrete-mathematics, simplex, semidefinite-programming

Suppose we have two unit vectors, $\mathbf{a}_1$ and $\mathbf{a}_2$, where $\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and $\|\mathbf{a}_1\|_2 = \|\mathbf{a}_2\|_2 =1$. Also, we have their inner product as $\langle\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2\rangle = \cos{\theta}$. Consider a random equilateral $(K-1)$-simplex $\Sigma_{K-1}$, $2\leq K<N$, that has vertices at $\mathbf{z}_1,\dots,\mathbf{z}_K$ and has the centroid at  $C_{K-1}=\sum_{k=1}^K \mathbf{z}_k/ K$. Let the vector from centroid to the $k$-th vertex as $\mathbf{v}_k = \mathbf{z}_k-C_{K-1}$, $\forall k$ (for simplicity, we assume that  $\|\mathbf{v}_k\|_2=1,\forall k$). Define the following two vertex indices of the simplex for $\mathbf{a}_1$ and $\mathbf{a}_2$ respectively as
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&k_1 = \arg \max_k \langle\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{v}_k\rangle \ ,\\
&k_2 = \arg \max_k \langle\mathbf{a}_2,\mathbf{v}_k\rangle \ .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
What is the probability of $k_1=k_2$? Can this probability be expressed in $\theta$ and $K$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show own attempts. Even if you did it just in 2D.

Comment: I know that the probability is $\theta/pi$ in 2D. This is because $1$-simplex is a line, and the probability of $k_1=k_2$ is equal to that $\mathbf{a}_1$ and $\mathbf{a}_2$ on the same side of the hyperplane perpendicular to the line. However, I have no idea how to approach this further. Helps will be appreciated. Thx. @KurtG.